# reverse geocoding to find exact organization/building/landmark name that location

Tags: python, geocoding, reverse-geocoding

When I search  about an  organization in google maps,along with map location, there is side  pop up where  other  details like adress,ph no etc show  up.

I  know  the python coding to find cordinates  for an address.

but  I  am notable to find  the a way to extract name of  the  organization from the  address.

Is there a way to program( python preferred) to  find the organization/building/landmark name for  which I only have the address ?

Note : Through web scraping I can find the address of the organization from its web-site but  how do  I find the name of organization if I  have only its address or cordinates

Eg : search 'Ajanta Chemical Industries' on google map and you get below address

Office & Factory 812/ E-9, 10 11 & 12, Samtel Zone, Phase- III, RIICO Industrial Area, Bhiwadi, Rajasthan 301019

Question - If I  have above address , is  there a programmable  way to  find that its for 'Ajanta Chemical Industries'  ?

Comment: Have you checked the [Maps Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start)?